# View my custom entity as a normal page in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I created a custom entity with the drupal 8 console. Everything works fine. However, when I am logged in as an administrator, my entity appears in an admin page instead of a normal page like for nodes.

In this case, the title and the edit links (tabs) are displayed in the gray bar of the administration.

How to make my entity appear as a node without the gray bar of aministration?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the permission from admin to view to entity to anonymous user then you can view without login.